# Windows Phone company app on a developer unlocked phone

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8, app-hub

I was wondering if it is possible to install a “company app hub” app on a developer unlocked Windows Phone?

The reason I ask is because for my University dissertation I am considering creating a "company app hub" template for SMB's etc. unfortunately I won't qualify for a business account.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The Company app hub (ssp.xap) file must be code-signed by your own Company certificate and the Company App Hub app only Works with MS InTune. But you can build your own Company Hub App, by using the Windows.Phone.Management.Deployment api.

Comment: Thanks for your response. To confirm I would be able to test one via the emulator and phone but not install an official final version?